# Order management SQL schema

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am designing a SQL database for sales person of a firm, where each customer will order multiple items from the firm. I want to store this order uniquely to the customer. Which will be linked to customer table.

Customer Table :

- Cust_id
- Cust_name
- Cust_phone

Currently I am thinking of making a separate order table for each order

Order Table:

- Product_id
- Prod_quantity
- Total_amt

but can't figure out how to link it back to customer. Or how to uniquely identify each order table.
I would have done it in NoSQL but data has to be locally stored in SQLite.
Customer may order multiple times so I should be able to identify current and previous orders

Answer (score 5):

Do **not** create a separate table for each order! That's a very bad design. Relational tables aren't spreadsheets!

Have one table for the orders with a foreign key pointing to the customers. For the items of orders have a linking table with a foreign key to the order and another to the item. That's fairly standard thing (I'm pretty certain you'll find such a classic example in many tutorials about relational database design.). Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE customer
             (id integer,
              name varchar(64),
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE product
             (id integer,
              name varchar(64),
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE order
             (id integer,
              customer integer,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (customer)
                          REFERENCES customer
                                     (id));

CREATE TABLE order_product
             (order integer,
              product integer,
              amount integer,
              ...
              PRIMARY KEY (order,
                           product),
              FOREIGN KEY (order)
                          REFERENCES order
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (customer)
                          REFERENCES customer
                                     (id));
```

(`order` might be a bad choice for a table or column name in some DBMS as it's also a keyword and thus required quoting. So probably chose something else. I used it just for the sake of clarity.)